# Database operation in android

Tags: android, database

In my application I have to created a table with 2 columns and 5 rows. Now I need to update 5 values at a time.I have 1 screen with 5 `EditText`s and a save `Button`.After clicking save the values in the 5 edit boxes should be updated in the database.Can anybody help me with the query?Thanks in advance.

My table structure is:

```
id    name
1     wee
2     fvfb
3     erer
4     fgfg
5     fggfg

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =

"create table incomexpense(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"+"price text not null,description text not null,"+"quantity text not null,"+"total text not null,"+"category text not null,"+"recurrence text not null,"+"date text not null,"+"groups text not null);";


private static final String DATABASE_TABLESPIN = "create table spinner(_id primary key autoincrement,"+" spin text not null);";
```

But only one table is displayed??Help me..

Comment: which database u using qslite or mysql ?

Comment: And i think u will need  a array which will count the number of rows in ur database

Answer (score 1):

**This Class Will Create a table..You Can Create your Required Fields editing this class.**

```
public class TableCreater extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userregister.db";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "USER_SESSION";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String USER_ID = "user_id";

    public static final String TABLE_CREATE =

    "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement," + USER_ID + " integer);";

    public static final String FIRST_QUERY = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME
            + " (user_id) values(0);";

    public loginchecker(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(FIRST_QUERY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(loginchecker.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

**This method will update the data in the tables..You can edit as per your requirement**

```
public InsertingClass InsertID(int uid) 
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(loginchecker.USER_ID, uid);
        long insertedId = database.insert(loginchecker.TABLE_NAME, null,
                values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(loginchecker.TABLE_NAME, allColumnsLogin,
                loginchecker.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertedId, null, null,
                null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursorToModel(cursor);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Androider..My doubt is that i have created one database with 2 tables in that,but it showing only 1 table in sqlitebrowser.Y this is happening...I will edit my post with the code,,please refer that ..

Comment: i hope one of the table may not be getting created

Comment: I have edited my post..please refer and tell where i am going wrong??

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted above..I thing the query firing for the 2nd table may have some error..the string for creating the table looks fine to me..please check the lines where you have executed db.exeQuery() statement for the 2nd table..

Comment: Ya i got it..i solved that now its showing 2 tables...Now i am looking for updation query..can u please help me??

Comment: i have given you above insert query...similarly you can use the update method..can get it by just googling as sqlite update

Answer (score 0):

For creating tables see [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). And for crud operations with database see [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public boolean updateValue(long rowId, String useridvalue)
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(USER_ID, useridvalue);
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, args,
            COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```